# The code "dtype=bool" does not work on onnx model

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx

`mask = torch.zeros((src.shape[0],) + (src.shape[-2:]), dtype=bool, device=src.device)`

When I try to export the pytorch model into onnx model and run the onnx model, I find the the type of "mask" is bool on pth model, however, it is float32 on onnx model.

The version of some packages is as follows:

```
torchaudio               2.0.1+cu118
torchvision              0.15.1+cu118
onnx                     1.15.0
onnxruntime              1.16.3
onnxruntime-gpu          1.16.1
```

Comment: Can you check the values of the float32 mask? It might just be casting the bools to 1/0 represented as floats.

Comment: thank for your help, it works with your method!!